# PHP Почему после $statement->execute() страница перезагружается, если раньше использовался метод move_uploaded_file()?

Tags: php, header

Если загружен файл и выполняется `mkdir(dirname($imagePath));` или `move_uploaded_file()`, то когда программа доходит до функции   `$statement->execute();` страница просто перезагружается, т.е до строки header() программа не доходит. Не могу понять, почему `mkdir(...);` и `move_uploaded_file()` так влияет на `$statement->execute();`. При этом файл все равно перемещается в нужную папку и данные добавляются в базу после `$statement->execute();`.

```
if (empty($errors)) {
    if ($imageFile && $imageFile['tmp_name']) {
        $imagePath = 'img/' . randomString(8) . '/' . $imageFile['name'];

        mkdir(dirname($imagePath));
        move_uploaded_file($imageFile['tmp_name'], $imagePath);
    }

    $statement = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO products (title, description, image, price, create_date) VALUES (:title, :description, :image, :price, :create_date)');
    $statement->bindValue(':title', $title);
    $statement->bindValue(':description', $description);
    $statement->bindValue(':image', $imagePath);
    $statement->bindValue(':price', $price);
    $statement->bindValue(':create_date', $create_date);

    $statement->execute();
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Возможно, что-то выводится раньше, чем происходит вызов header(). Например, функция mkdir или move_uploaded_file выдает ошибку. P.S. Вы создаёте каталог, но файл перемещаете не в него. P.P.S. Если условие не выполняется, то переменная $imagePath не будет определена.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я уже понял, что проблема не в  header(), а в $statement->execute();. Теперь надо понять почему так происходит. Первое сообщение я отредактировал, в связи с тем, что ошибка оказалась в другом.

Comment: А где расположен скрипт, код из которого вы привели в вопросе? Ну и в конце концов, включите вывод ошибок.

Comment: Скрипт в файле "create.php", сперва идет php код, который обрабатывает данные, а потом блок html c формой ввода данных через submit.  Вывод ошибок включен (в файле PHP.ini - display_errors = on ), но ничего не отображает.  Методом многочасового тыкания, нашел как избавиться от ошибки. Если выключить live server, то все работает как надо, если его включить, сразу получаю описанные проблемы.